# Gnuplot - line over axis

Tags: gnuplot

I want to see my line from data over my xzeroaxis(right now I see black axis and not colour of my line), but I cant find way how to do it. This is my header of plot right now:

```
set style fill transparent solid 0.5 noborder
set terminal pngcairo nocrop enhanced font "verdana,8" size 1280,960
set xtics 720
set yrange[0:0.15]
set xdata time
set format x ' %H:%M:%S'
```

I tried to add

```
set/unset xzeroaxis
```

But its not working, I also tried to set different linestyle/ line width etc., but I still cant find the solution.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is incomplete code. What is your actual plot command, what is your output graph? Please provide a copy&paste reproducible example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have only plot '-' using ($1):2 with lines title 'ksmd utime + stime',  0.1with filledcurves x2 title 'threshold' lt rgb 'red'
 +  dataset after this header and I print with command gnuplot script > output

Comment: how does your data look like? Could you please provide a screenshot of the resulting graph, which visualizes your problem.

Comment: https://imgur.com/vtPZS1m     https://pastebin.com/DQFfLEHs     I want to see 0.0 values over axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, now I see...

The simplest way, set the lower y-range slightly negative:

```
set yrange[-0.01:0.15]
```

But you were probably looking for: `set border behind`. Check `help border`.

**Code:**

```
### put border behind graph
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1 0
2 0
3 1
4 0
5 0
EOD

set border behind

plot $Data u 1:2 w l lw 2
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: glad to hear. If it works then please mark the answer as acceptable to indicate: problem solved.